# Performance of external versus static function call

Tags: c, performance, static, c99, extern

Is there typically a difference in performance between calling an `extern` function versus calling a `static` function? If so, what causes this difference -- aren't both calls mapped the same way (i.e. to a specific machine address) via early binding?

Comment: One thing is sure: `static` functions can potentially be inlined, functions defined in a different translation unit cannot (at least not without the not-so-common LTO). Also, if the `extern` function is inside a dynamically linked library, there may be a cost loading the library (not sure about the runtime performace though, it may vary between systems and ABIs).

Comment: It's much "easier" for the compiler to inline a static function.  Inlining an external function defined in another translation module requires whole-program optimization (basically link-time optimization).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an implementation detail, entirely up to the compiler/linker. On Linux, calling a static function or an extern function in a statically-linked library are essentially the same, while calling a function in a shared library adds a level of indirection, and so is a bit slower.

Also, the compiler has more information about static functions and so can do more optimization, including potentially inlining.